# Display this type of data in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, graph, charts, kendo-ui, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm not sure if this belongs here, so here goes.

My tsql stored procedure returns data like this, for 16 groups. This is just Group 1-3:

```
Group   Hour  Avg
1       4     99.800
1       3     96.800
1       2     100.000
1       1     99.800
1       0     100.000
2       4     97.700
2       3     99.800
2       2     98.800
2       1     99.800
2       0     99.800
3       4     99.800
3       3     97.900
3       2     99.900
3       1     100.000
3       0     99.800
```

Essentially, the data simply shows the Avg/hr for each group.

I need to display this graphically somehow, but I want to emphasize, at the hourly level, what group went below 99%.

From the data, we can see that Group 2/Hr 4 dropped below 99. Since there are 15 other groups, there's a possibility that for that hour, several other groups went below the 99%. But when the users see the graph/chart, they immediately know which groups went below the threshold.

So I was considering a line chart/area chart, but there are too many lines. Using SSRS, the line chart looks something like this:

[image]

So I'm looking for suggestions on how to simplify this. Granted, I can simply use a text-based report, but people here love graphs and charts.

Also, I want the graph to be historical, which means it will display the failed groups throughout the day.

We also have Kendo charts, that's why there's a tag for this.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you're trying to do, but you need to take into account assimilation of the data. You can make something as pretty and colorful as you want, but if it becomes a "Where's Waldo" hunt to find the key piece of data a user needs, then you've still failed.

With 16 groups, I would recommend staying away from all charts and graphs. Instead, I would use a table that has something graphics embedded in the cells. For instance, you could use [sparklines or data bars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633676%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for each group.

Additionally, you could look at using [indicators](http://dynamicsgpinsights.com/2013/07/23/using-indicators-to-visualize-data-in-sql-server-reporting-services-reports/) inside your table.

Also, don't forget about dynamically changing text color, background colors, borders, font size, and borders to make certain groups pop. Your goal in designing a page should be to have progressively more complex displays draw the user's eyes from one part of the page to another. In doing this well, you can tell a story that is easily assimilated all while using a dynamic report. Actually mastering this skill is another issue entirely, but start working towards it, never settle for something being good enough, and before you know it, you'll have an eye-popping report.